# How to assign values to a class and create json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to assign values to a class to build a JSON string. The goal is to generate something as shown below.

```
    {
    "ProductType" : "Spotlight_Comp",
        "SimulatedData" : [ 
            {
                "value" : 1819.00923045901,
                "units" : "hp",
                "tag" : "comp/totalIhp",
                "name" : "Compressor - Total IHP"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : 789.294125,
                "units" : "RPM",
                "tag" : "comp/averageSpeed",
                "name" : "Compressor - Speed"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : 2064.74658240481,
                "units" : "hp",
                "tag" : "comp/totalBhp",
                "name" : "Compressor - Total BHP"
            }
    ]
}
```

But i am having issues with figuring out the correct syntax to create the array of objects for the `SimulatedData` key. Below, is my code. I've tried various different syntax and haven't been able to achieve a solution.

```
public static void CreateJson(string productType, string units, string simTag, string name, string value)
        {
            Simulator.Root data = new Simulator.Root
            {
                ProductType = productType,
                SimulatedData =
                {

                }  
                //SimulatedData = new SimulatedData { value = value, units = units, tag = simTag, name = name }
            };

            string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonOutput);
        }
```

Code for classes to build JSON below

```
      public class Root
        {
            public string ProductType { get; set; }
            public SimulatedData[] SimulatedData { get; set; }
        }

        public class SimulatedData
        {
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
            public string units { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

I am sure that the way I have my classes structured is throwing me off. But this is the approach that i thought was best at the moment. I have a hunch that the issue is with having a class called `SimulatedData` and then having a property in Root for `SimulatedData[]`.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=MXk4uVJWvWYZivYlqAtI

Comment: this also works! THANKS A BUNCH!

Answer (score 1):

If you have one object then the following should work.

```
Simulator.Root data = new Simulator.Root
{
    ProductType = productType,
    SimulatedData = new []{new SimulatedData { value = value, units = units, tag = simTag, name = name }}
};
```

For multiple objects just create a List, or an array and assign it to `SimulatedData` property:

```
var l = new List<SimulatedData>();

l.Add(...);
l.Add(...);
l.Add(...);

Simulator.Root data = new Simulator.Root
{
    ProductType = productType,
    SimulatedData = l.ToArray()
};
```

You could also change Root to keep a list, not an array.

```
public List<SimulatedData> SimulatedData { get; set; }
```

Comment: this works great! I'm going to make some code changes you requested. I confused myself by creating an array property. Thank you!